# Attempting to edit a post in the "Late Answers" review queue fails silently if the post has pending suggested edits

Tags: bug, edits, editing-help, late-answers

While reviewing the late answers, I tried to edit the answer to format it properly, but the  edit link is disabled and there is no error message. I can't edit the answer despite clicking a few times. 
[image: 1st Place]

I decided to check the question outside of the queue, and when clicking the "edit" link on the answer it displays the error message:

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

[image: 2nd Place]

When attempting to edit this same post inside the review queue, the same error should be displayed.

I do not know if this only happens for those who have less than 2k
reputation.

Comment: @yivi I am reviewing the late answers and I am unable edit the answer someone already edited the answer and edit is awaiting for approval. At the same time, I am trying to edit answer and not seeing edit is waiting for approval message. I do not have 2K reputation so I am seeing this as bug.

Comment: I had a bit of trouble understanding the first version of your question. I tried to edit it to make it bit clearer. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: @yivi sorry for my bad language. Thanks for the edits. I want you to understand issue before any negative feedback